# CSS for style change - Not working with chrome

Tags: html, css, tags, styles

```
li.disabled a {color : #808080;}
```

I've added the above in .css file and my expectation is to find any `<li>` tag with class as disabled and make the corresponding content given in `<a href="#">???</a>` this tag to be displayed as gray in colour.

Example of my html would be http://pastebin.com/cnA4gqb3

This does not seem to work on browser like chrome. Can you suggest me a generic css which will work in common across all browsers?

Comment: This is probably a "importancy" issue. Some other CSS is likely to be more important to Chrome. Try adding !important or change the order of your rules.

Comment: also check to see if you have set a style for a:visited or a:active as this may be overriding the colour too

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem on chrome using your code, and the css you're using seems pretty standard to me. Can you provide some additional informations like surrounding html code and css ?

Comment: [Works on chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/8edPs/).

Comment: As reinder pointed out, its importancy issue only. Thanks guys. @reinder Please post this as answer if possible so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a "importancy" issue. Some other CSS is likely to be more important to Chrome. Try adding !important or change the order of your rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

This is used for safari and chrome basically,

`@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { #u { color:green; /* Safari only */ } }